# build error: unknown field 'HideWindow'

Tags: go

I'm making multi-platform Gui applications with golang and Qt. The application executes an external command.

In Windows, a DOS window is displayed when executing the external command. I gave the HideWindow attribute so as not to display this.

```
  command := exec.Command("hoge", "fuga")
  command.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true}
```

this code works well in Windows, but the following error occurred in the build for MacOS.

```
unknown field 'HideWindow' in struct literal of type syscall.SysProcAttr
```

I modified the code as below, but I can not avoid the error. Are there any ideas?

```
 if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
  command.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true}
 }
```

Comment: `HideWindow` doesn't exist at all if you're not on windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot fix a compile-time error with a run-time check. You'll need to use [build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) to create separate implementations compatible with each platform. To stay DRY, you'll likely want to create a function that only handles the platform-specific behavior(s), so that the cross-platform code can then call into the platform-specific function (which may be a no-op on platforms that need no platform-specific behavior). So you might have a file for Windows, one for MacOS, and one for Linux (or whatever set of platforms you're supporting), each with a function like:

```
// +build darwin

package whatever

func prepareBackgroundCommand(cmd *exec.Cmd) {
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true}
}
```

And another like:

```
// +build !darwin

package whatever

func prepareBackgroundCommand(cmd *exec.Cmd) {
}
```

So that in your main (non-platform-specific) code, you can call `prepareBackgroundCommand(command)` and it will handle it correctly based on the platform it's being compiled for.

Comment: Should be `// +build windows` and `// +build !windows`. It's not like there is only two platforms, Windows and macOS. And, I can compile from anywhere with `xgo`, anyways.